# Centering an element within a footer?

Tags: html, layout, alignment, footer

I'm fairly knew to this. A recent update has thrown my 'special recent posts pro' widget out of alignment in my footer. I've moved the item to an 'above footer' container. I was hoping to make it fixed width, say 1000px, and center it within the container.

[www.richclarkimages.co.uk](http://www.richclarkimages.co.uk)

Any ideas on how to achieve this?

Comment: Please post the relevant bits of code from your site. Your question will be more useful to others that way.

Comment: www.richclarkimages.co.uk/media="all"
.srp-container-single-row {
    -webkit-box-orient: horizontal;
    -moz-box-orient: horizontal;
    -webkit-flex-direction: row;
    -moz-flex-direction: row;
    -ms-flex-direction: row;
    flex-direction: row;
    -webkit-flex-wrap: nowrap;
    -moz-flex-wrap: nowrap;
    -ms-flex-wrap: nowrap;
    flex-wrap: nowrap;
}

Comment: Maybe my first question should have been how do I obtain the relevant code from the Developer Tools. ;)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are several issues with the markup on your site. I see you are using WordPress, so I am guessing that you did not write all the code yourself.

As far as I can tell, the element with the class `.srp-widget.container` has its width set to 1000px, so to center that in the parent container, only a little CSS is required.

```
.srp-widget.container {
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto;
}
```

Comment: Henrik many thanks. I'm embarrassed to say that this was how I resolved the issue last time but it had slipped my mind. Yep the Wordpress theme is Photocrati and I have simply changed a few elements and tweaked the css in places.  A little knowledge is dangerous as they say. I know there are cross browser issues I'm working on. A work in progress. I owe you a beer or two.

Comment: If you click the accept button next to the answer that helps. ;-)